# Protractor in a Docker container - Wait for full page to load

Tags: angularjs, docker, protractor

This is my first post on StackOverflow so please be gentle.

I'm running some Protractor tests with a Docker container.
The tests work nicely out of the container, but in it, protractor doesn't wait for some Angular ajax calls to totally fill some div.

```
it('Should check first years are equal', function () {
    var firstElementFirstYear = $$('div.cumulated div.street-table-value.ng-scope div.ng-binding.ng-scope').get(8).getInnerHtml().then(function(text) {return text.trim();});
    var secondElementFirstYear = $$('div.cumulated div.street-table-value.ng-binding.ng-scope').get(8).getInnerHtml().then(function(text) {return text.trim();});
    expect(firstElementFirstYear).toEqual(secondElementFirstYear);
},10000);
```

Then I get an **Index out of bounds exception**.

I tried :

- to use a waitForAngular in the beforeEach.
- a wait for an expected condition (count>9) to be met but it gets timedout
- browser.sleep(4000) before getting the elements
- tried to locate my elements with the protractor debug tool, launching chrome browser and I get my 10 elements correctly when I locate them manually

But I don't manage to get all the elements needed, the number of elements stays at 5 and never go to 10.

What else could I try to wait for Angular to finish the ajax calls and populate my divs?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the problematic code.

Comment: this isn't to protactor to wait. It's you that must wait the promise to be resolved using `then` and dn't you use$httpBackend to mock the server side ?

Comment: `$$('div.someclass').get(8);` returns a promise that you have to resolve. So you do `$$('div.someclass').get(8).then(function(data) {});`

Comment: I did try to wait for the promise to be resolved with a wait (and a synchronize disable) but the condition was never met. Except out of the docker container, it is met. 

I updated the example I used.

Comment: Since version 5.0.0 protractor no longer supports `getInnerHtml()` on elements. https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/0555d394ce87eb7d12cbf3a33881dac54fb740fd

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm on 4.0.14 so it's still working. And it breaks before. I don't get all the elements I am supposed to.

Protractor just tells me that it doesn't have the index I'm trying to get. I don't understand why I have this behavior only inside the docker.

Comment: Maybe try to find these elements by something else, like model or id? If protractor can't find them then there isn't much you can do except change the way you look for it.

Comment: I already tried to add some ids at some point but couldn't add some specific ones. The method generating this is used in multiple places for different contexts. And it would repeat the same behavior everywhere so I realized it wasn't an option for me, the method is too generic.

I still think that since I can't reach the same dom as the one I see with an inspector, everything is not fully loaded when I try to get the elements...

Oh and I didn't mock anything with httpBackend, I want to access real data I'm generating without any mock. But thanks for evoking this path.

Comment: It may be that some of the elements you need are hidden in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right @FCin, the elements were in fact hidden. I adjusted the screen resolution when launching the headless protractor container with :

```
-e SCREEN_RES=1920x1080x24
```

And that was it! Thanks!